# How to copy text to clipboard using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need a bit help.. How to copy data automatically to the clipboard from the textbox?
This is a part of the programm, I already tried a few things..

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(sor, 1).Value = serial
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value = futo
UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = serial
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

Dim MyData As DataObject

Set MyData = New DataObject
MyData.SetText UserForm1.TextBox1
MyData.PutInClipboard

End If
```

Comment: It looks like DataObjects have some 32/64 bit issues, you might want to check out [this post](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/1/13/how-to-use-vba-code-to-copy-text-to-the-clipboard) about using an HTML object to make a function to handle clipboard access.

Comment: `Dim MyData As New DataObject` and delete `Set MyData = New DataObject`.

Comment: @FaneDuru that makes it an auto-instantiated object, which can cause very unexpected and surprising bugs. Rule of thumb, avoid `As New` if you can help it.\

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing the TextBox object, not the Text property of it.  Try this.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(sor, 1).Value = serial
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value = futo
UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = serial
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

Dim MyData As New DataObject

MyData.SetText UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
MyData.PutInClipboard
```

End If

Comment: It doesn't work.. "Object required" error message pops up

Comment: It signs this line: MyData.SetText UserForm1.TextBox1.Text

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put the value of "serial" variable in clipboard
the easiest way to put it in cell and copy the cell

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(sor, 1).copy
```

it works well specially if the value is Unicode Characters